# Not able to load mysql query data in JEasyUI Grid

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, jquery-easyui

I am new to PHP and JEasy UI.
I am actually running the demo application of JEasy UI Grid. 
Whereas I am not getting the data from Php file to Grid.

Any Idea or suggestion please...!!

Below is My Code:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Basic CRUD Application - jQuery EasyUI CRUD Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-info" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div class="demo-tip icon-tip">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
            url="http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud/get_users.php"
            toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
            rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="firstname" width="50">First Name</th>
                <th field="lastname" width="50">Last Name</th>
                <th field="phone" width="50">Phone</th>
                <th field="email" width="50">Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newUser()">New User</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editUser()">Edit User</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="destroyUser()">Remove User</a>
    </div>

    <div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:400px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px"
            closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
        <div class="ftitle">User Information</div>
        <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input name="firstname" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input name="lastname" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Phone:</label>
                <input name="phone">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input name="email" class="easyui-validatebox" validType="email">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dlg-buttons">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="saveUser()">Save</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url;
        function newUser(){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
            $('#fm').form('clear');
            url = 'save_user.php';
        }
        function editUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
                $('#fm').form('load',row);
                url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
            }
        }
        function saveUser(){
            $('#fm').form('submit',{
                url: url,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    return $(this).form('validate');
                },
                success: function(result){
                    var result = eval('('+result+')');
                    if (result.errorMsg){
                        $.messager.show({
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.errorMsg
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function destroyUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
                    if (r){
                        $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                            if (result.success){
                                $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                            } else {
                                $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    msg: result.errorMsg
                                });
                            }
                        },'json');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #fm{
            margin:0;
            padding:10px 30px;
        }
        .ftitle{
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding:5px 0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .fitem{
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        .fitem label{
            display:inline-block;
            width:80px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code URL

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud/get_users.php

Answer (score 0):

to get the data from datagrid you need to code like this

```
   public function get_user(){

    /*Default request pager params from jeasyUI*/
    $offset = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $limit  = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['itemid'] : '';
    $offset = ($offset-1)*$limit;

    //change this line to yours
    $data   = $this->user_model->get_user($offset,$limit,$search); 
    $i  = 0;
    $rows   = array(); 
    foreach ($data ['data'] as $r) {

       $rows[$i]['first_name'] = $r->first_name;
       $rows[$i]['last_name'] = $r->last_name;
       $rows[$i]['phone'] = $r->phone;
       $rows[$i]['email'] = $r->email;

     $i++;
    }

    //keys total & rows is required on jEasyUI
    $result = array('total'=>$data['count'],'rows'=>$rows);
    echo json_encode($result);
 }
```

more complete example [here](http://teknosains.com/i/menampilkan-data-dari-mysql-ke-datagrid-jeasyui-dengan-codeigniter)